# HD making noise

Tags: hard-drive, noise

So, I've bought an HDD from a guy, he said it was good and everything.

Well, turns out this HDD makes a terrible noise every now and then, it seems to be screaming. My PC was very silent and this is bothering me a lot.

I ran S.M.A.R.T check and got nice results overall:

[image: hd with bad sectors making noise]

But then at the Write check was when the problem stood out. It's noisy all around, specially when it hits a block > 150ms.

This is the results of the reading scan. Took around 2~3 hours to complete:
[image]

I've recorded a video with the sound:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1yDrZvPNw3o

Is there a way to make this noise go away or must I replace the HDD? Does it indicate a potential failure in the near future?

Comment: The person you bought the HDD from lied to you.  The HDD should be replaced immediately

Comment: Judging from the sounds there's an issue with the head that reads/writes the data in the HDD, probably a mechanical issue. Depending on what it is exactly, repair of these parts - if possible - is really pricey. I suggest you store nothing on there for which you don't have a backup.